# Do Public Land Survey System Townships have names? If so, why are they often left out of shapefiles

Tags: geonames, plss

I am having trouble identifying names for PLSS townships. I am beginning to think it is because I am confusing political townships/PLSS townships/others.

Could anyone clarify whether or not PLSS townships have names? If so, could anyone explain why it seems many files omit them?

Answer (score 5):

PLSS townships themselves do not have names, but in many places do overlap with named civil townships, which are typically smaller local government units within counties. For example, T10N R3R in Shelby County Illinois overlaps with Lakewood Township. But in many other places civil townships only partially overlap with PLSS townships or are not designated at all. Shapefiles of PLSS townships don't include the names since they are not always the same entities, but they do show up on USGS topo maps. You can find a more detailed description of the Township/Range/Section PLSS system [here](https://nationalmap.gov/small_scale/a_plss.html), and a short description of the difference between civil and PLSS townships [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Township_(United_States)).

[image]

Various websites offer ways to search by location and get Section, Range, and Township information (including civil township name, if one exists). For example, the [ISGS PLSS site](http://isgs.illinois.edu/plss) is a helpful resource. Similar websites exist for other parts of the country.

Comment: Thank you. From the second link, I think I'm seeing the distinction/what's happening here. I do see that it seems like the name is actually carried over from civil townships. AM I understanding that correctly?

Comment: See: "Township and precinct names were obtained from the Census Bureau's 2012 TIGER/Line geospatial data. Civil township/precinct boundaries do not exactly match the PLSS townships and ranges, although in many areas of the state the two systems are coincident.

Township and precinct names are provided as a convenience to the user [...]"

Comment: Does *every* township in the US have an associated name, such as "Lakewood"?  I've spent my entire life in Oregon, Washington, and Alaska working with PLSS data, and I've never come across such names.  I've always described them as Jeffery Evans states.  Have I missed out?

Comment: Good question, @StuSmith-- I didn't know that. I've worked mostly in the Midwest, and all Townships have names here. The names are generally pretty old too, and you can find them even on plat books from the 1800's. Scrolling through USGS topo maps around the country though, it looks like named townships are primarily a Midwestern phenomenon. Once you get west of the Dakotas, townships don't seem to be named anymore.

Comment: They are just coincidences. There would be a Lakewood Township, complete with elected board of commissioners, with boundaries falling neatly within that 36 square mile box. But next door there might be a Nerdsville Township, only 25 square miles big... Certainly they are not simply nicknames for TyN RxE, but at least at one time had a real townhall, etc.

Comment: Real simple, just go in any direction until you encounter an irregularly shaped county. There will be at least one township there that also isn't a 6 x 6 mile rectangle too, as civil townships don't cross county lines. E.g., it will only go up to the river, while the TyN RxE will ignore the river.

Comment: I just checked a "Shelby County, Illinois - Townships Map". Only about 1/3 of that county's civil townships are 6 x 6 miles, and fit into one PLSS township. Just like not every house is one on lot of land, nor does every lot of land contain exactly one house. Myth busted.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_township says right off the bat: Not to be confused with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_township .

Comment: I completely forgot about this 5 year old answer, @DanJacobson. You're right, of course. Thanks for dropping a comment so I could update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The PLSS is a gridded system with numeric ID's identifying each township and range with N,S,E,W grid divisions, and associated sections eg., "T7N R2W section 14" would be a common naming convertio but, the attributes are often stored in separate columns. To get more specific, deceptively, you start defining divisions in the sections (aliquot parts) eg., "T7N R2W NE of SE of section 14" which defines the NW quarter in the SW quarter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's what I came to think, but I'm seeing both PLSSID/numeric IDs as well as names (and most times where said names come from doesn't seem clear) on maps... but they rarely appear in the raw data. Have you noticed this on maps/have idea why they'd exist on some? The answer above provides an example in the second link. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

PLSS townships don't have names, only numbers.

Allow us to examine a map of say, Shelby County Illinois townships [[source](https://shelby.il.bhamaps.com/)],

[image: Shelby Co. IL townships]

At first look Cold Spring Township fits nicely into TyN RxE. If we went to bed at this point we might imagine that that's how the Lord made most of them.

However a close look at some of the other townships shatter that illusion. E.g, Lakewood Township is 6 x 5 miles, no comfy 6 x 6 mile fit.

So it would be best to get it out of your mind that there is some ordained connection... Don't just take my word for it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_township says: "not to be confused with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survey_township " and vice versa.